# there is a retired plod

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the bold part, please tell me about it?
**Perhaps there is a retired plod** with a 50-year-old duty roster that can give us a more definitive idea of how officers then spent their time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***British informal:*** A police officer.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plod)

(Oxford Living Dictionaries)

A duty [roster](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/roster) is "a list of ... personnel [police officers, in this case], specifically one showing their regular assignments and periods of duty."

(Collins Dictionary)

The writer apparently believes that 50 years ago police officers in the UK performed different duties than they do today.

Comment: If it means "A police officer", why after that said "with a 50-year-old duty roster "?

Comment: Do my edits help?

Comment: What did you said?

Comment: A duty roster is "a list of ... personnel [police officers, in this case], specifically one showing their regular assignments and periods of duty."

(Collins Dictionary)

The writer apparently believes that 50 years ago police officers in the UK performed different duties than they do today.